# jquery variable does not show value out of each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following jquery code:

```
var imgArr = {};
var imgAttrib = $(selector).map(function() {
    imgArr.src = $(this).attr('src');
    imgArr.id = $(this).attr('id');
    imgArr.height = $(this).attr('height');
    imgArr.width = $(this).attr('width');
    //console.log(imgArr);
    imgAttrib.push(imgArr);
    console.log("imageAttrib is ");
    console.log(imgAttrib);
});
console.log("FINAL imageAttrib is ");
console.log(imgAttrib);
```

When I check my console, for each iteration the console prints:

```
imageAttrib is:
[Object{src="some_url",id="123"...]
```

However after the loop it prints:

```
FINAL imageAttrib is:
Object[]
```

As you can see the imageAttrib becomes empty after the loop, but has value inside it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're not returning anything from your callback, so there's nothing to map. you put all the values into imgArr. imgAttrib.push will cause an error because its undefined

Comment: What is the selector? The immediate problem I see is you never reinitialize imgArr so each time you are just overwriting the properties of the same object reference.

Comment: @Shanimal is right. You should probably just us an `each` or `forEach` instead. You are not really using `map` properly

Comment: @shanimal is right. You need to return value from .map() function.

Comment: thank you guys, I now see that the problem was that I was not returning value from map...

Answer (score 1):

You never `return` - and you're using `.map` a bit wrong - here's a modified version:

```
var imgAttrib = $(selector).map(function() {
    return {
        src: this.src,
        id: this.id,
        height: $(this).attr('height'),
        width: $(this).attr('width')
    }
}).get();
```

Comment: That works, thank you. Can you tell me why we need to use .get() in the end?

Comment: @UndefinedVariable -- The original returned object from jQuery's `.map` is an object containing the array. `.get()` just transforms the result to a basic array. - http://api.jquery.com/map/ - official explanation is right under the description.